# How can i have a base controller that has a prefix route in net core 3

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2

Actually i'm working with .NET Core 3,

and i have Controllers with a route like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("customers/app")]
public class CustomerAppController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

What i would like to do, is having a Base controller where i can put many things i want for all controllers, including a route prefix, like this:

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class CoreController : ControllerBase
{
    protected virtual Object HandleException(Exception ex, string path, ILogger logger)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex, "Unhandled exception.");
        return StatusCode(5000, new { ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Then the Controller would be:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("customers/app")]
public class CustomerAppController : CoreController
{

    //TODO: put actions here

    public override Object HandleException(Exception ex, string path, ILogger logger) { }
}
```

How can i make this work?

I found i can use this method:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UsePathBase("/api/v1");
        //other things
    }
```

Now i can call my api using `localhost/api/v1/randompath`, but it works too if i use `localhost/randompath`

Answer (score 0):

Add the Route attr to your controller and set the path over there.

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
```

in your respective controllers. I am using .net core web api and it works for me by this approach, without having to use app.UsePathBase(). If i set the path as /api/v1/ i cant access the api by the url pattern /api/[Controller] without supplementing with v1.